# Laravel 4.*: Get all cookies

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

How to get all cookies in Laravel 4.*? With:

```
Cookie::get($name)
```

I can get only one but I need to get them all even if I do not know their names.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you omit the `$name`, it should return all Cookies:

```
$cookies = Cookie::get();
```